# C# Owin Security Providers returning private IP for Request.Host instead of domain

Tags: c#, iis, oauth-2.0, owin

Using Owin for OAuth2 external logins, the redirect_uri sent to Google for instance, is the private IP address location of the C# app instead of the API domain. I traced it down to Owin setting the default Host with:

`HostString(OwinHelpers.GetHost(this));`

And the providers just use this value as the default host in the redirect_uri param with their authentication redirect. How do I make the default host send the domain name instead of a private IP address?

Answer (score 1):

Owin will send the `Host` header from the current http request. Your problem arises from the client that is using the ip address (or maybe `localhost` if you are executing requests locally) instead of the domain name.

Owin has no way to known your domain name other than retrieving it from the `Host` header.